# Google Kix editor - how to send data using POST?

Tags: php, google-closure, google-closure-library

Can I include this text editor for [Google Docs](http://docs.google.com) to my project?

https://github.com/benjamn/kix-standalone

or this is illegal?

I suspect that this person just steal the code. If this legal how can I send the data using POST to PHP? The HTML code does not have a textarea to send it, and I couldn't find a way to send the data.

Comment: Do not think that sending POST to PHP is different that sending POST to Node or anything else.

Comment: If you see code on a public Github, in the vast majority of cases the user wishes for other people to use it. Check the license, and if you are not sure, contact the author through github. If by "illegal" you mean "against license conditions", the author should be able to let you know. Email them `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's illegal because this code is not provided by Google. One reason is that it is heavily based on server-side components see this

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/closure-library-discuss/SeZdenR-2vA

and the link you provided contains the obfuscated code and you will have no support if you use it.

hope this help

Comment: Indeed, even the [README](https://raw.github.com/benjamn/kix-standalone/master/README) from benjamn's github project states "Although they have not released the source code for this editor, nor have they stated any intention of doing so ...". I would presume this code is fully closed source and not use it in any project.